# io-ts: only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript

I'm very new to TypeScript and faced the following problem.

```
import * as t from "io-ts";

interface Test {
    s: string
}

export const testTypeV = t.type({
    test: Test //Error: 'Test' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
})
```

What's wrong with the code? How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not declaring the type of `testTypeV` but making a variable assignment - the compiler is complaining that you are trying to assign the value of the key `test` to a type. Instead you need a value of type `Test`, for instance:

```
export const testTypeV = t.type({ test: { s: 'any-string' } });
```

The type of `testTypeV` is whatever is returned by `t.type`.